# Questions on Stirling Number of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics

I understand the concepts on Stirling number but I don't seem to be able to grasp and apply them to problems, such as this one:

Let $|A|=10$.  Find the number of partitions that A have, that contains 2 classes with 3 elements, and 1 class with 4 elements.

Can someone explain how to apply Stirling number of the second kind here?  It's not really making any sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would not use Stirling numbers to solve this problem. There are $\binom{10}4$ ways to choose the elements for the $r$-element class; that leaves $6$ elements to be split into two $3$-element classes. Let $a$ be a particular one of the $6$ elements not yet chosen. When we split them into two $3$-element subsets, one will contain $a$, and the other won’t. Moreover, if we know the one that contains $a$, we also know the other one: it’s all of the remaining $3$ elements. There are $\binom52$ ways to pick $2$ of the other $5$ unchosen elements to form a $3$-element set containing $a$, so there are $\binom52$ ways to split the $6$ unchosen elements into two $3$-element sets.

Altogether, then, there are $$\binom{10}4\binom52=210\cdot10=2100$$ partitions of $A$ into two $3$-element sets and one $4$-element set.